# How to see kendo.js methods in the console / while debugging?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm using `.kendoTabStrip` and it have some methods like `.reload`. I'm looking at [this doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/methods/reload) and what I'm doing is:

```
let tabStrip = $(".k-tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
debugger
console.log(tabStrip)
tabStrip.reload("li.k-state-active")
```

`$(".k-tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip");` is equivalent to creating a tabStrip like in the [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/methods/reload), I'm just accessing it in a different way.

The strange part is that when I do the `console.log` or I inspect `tabStrip` while debugging, I can't see the methods like `.reload` like in the pictures below.

**Debug**

[image]

**Console**

[image]

But when I access the method, it's there, `.reload` exits even though I can't see it in other ways.

**Accessing the variable**

[image]

Why this is happening here and how can I see the `.reload` methods (or all the others) while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because that reference is in fact the Kendo's `Widget` object from which `TabStrip` *inherits*(as seen [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.tabstrip.js#L178)). To see the TabStrip's methods you have to expand the `__proto__` property:

[image]